# Migrating to Seam 2.3 + JSF2 + RichFaces4 causes problems in Conversation Scope

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, seam2

I am in the process of migrating from Seam 2.2.2 (JSF1.2,Richfaces3), that was running on a Tomcat 7 (so no EJB at all), to maven-based multi-project Seam 2.3 Final (with JSF2, Richfaces4) deployed as ear-package on a JBoss 7.1.1.

After changing all necessary xml schemas and Richfaces tags (a:support, a:form etc..) step by step it is basically running. Except one strange behavior regarding the long-running conversations. They just dont get propagated to long LRC anymore. Every click is creating a new temporary one.
After hours of pain I found out that the binding of the template seems to be the cause.

My template gets chosen depending on the tenant you're logged in with - it is basically a SessionScope bean holding the name of the skin directory. Like so:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/taglib"
            xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
            template="skins/#{skin.name}/templates/template.xhtml"
            xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
```

As soon as I replace `#{skin.name}` with a particular name, propagating to LRC seems to work.

This has been working perfectly with Seam 2.2.

Anyone any idea what's the problem here?

Comment: Update: as mentioned in https://community.jboss.org/thread/213593?tstart=0 it is related to this issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-4976.
For me the proposed workaround is working